# How to call a child attribute from a parent class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to change the attributes _controller and progress of the class TrackingElementState in the _DetailPageState class in the function function(). Is there a simple way to do it?

Sorry, I am new into Flutter, so I need help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

  final Future<SharedPreferences> prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // TRY THIS: Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see
        // the application has a purple toolbar. Then, without quitting the app,
        // try changing the seedColor in the colorScheme below to Colors.green
        // and then invoke "hot reload" (save your changes or press the "hot
        // reload" button in a Flutter-supported IDE, or press "r" if you used
        // the command line to start the app).
        //
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // state is not lost during the reload. To reset the state, use hot
        // restart instead.
        //
        // This works for code too, not just values: Most code changes can be
        // tested with just a hot reload.
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 14, 53, 86)
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
      controller: controller,
      children:const
      [DetailPage(headline: 'Heute'),
      DetailPage(headline: "Gestern"),
      DetailPage(headline: 'Vorgestern',)])
    );
  }
}

class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const DetailPage({super.key, required this.headline});
  final String headline;

  @override
  State<DetailPage> createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(32, 50, 32, 32),
        child: ListView(
  children: [
        Column(children: [
          Text(widget.headline, style: const TextStyle(fontSize:30, color: Colors.white)),
          TrackingElement(color: Colors.yellow, text: "m", icon: Icons.directions_run, max: 5000, headline: widget.headline),
          TrackingElement(color: Colors.blue, text: "l", icon: Icons.local_drink, max: 3000, headline: widget.headline),
          TrackingElement(color: Colors.red, text: "kcal", icon: Icons.fastfood, max: 2500, headline: widget.headline),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 30, 0, 0),
          child: ElevatedButton(
            style:  ButtonStyle(
              backgroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(const Color.fromARGB(255, 0, 0, 0)),
                  foregroundColor:
                  MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255))
            ),
            onPressed: () => function(widget.headline),
            child: const Text('Löschen'),
          )),
        ],)
      ]));
    
  }

  function(String headline){
    }
}
}

class TrackingElement extends StatefulWidget {
  const TrackingElement({super.key, this.color, required this.text, required this.icon, required this.max, required this.headline});

  final Color? color;
  final String text;
  final IconData icon;
  final double max;
  final String headline;

  @override
  State<TrackingElement> createState() => TrackingElementState();
}

class TrackingElementState extends State<TrackingElement> {

  int _counter = 0;
  double progress = 0;
  var now = DateTime.now();
  String _storageKey = "";
  String headline = "";

  void _incrementCounter()async{
    setState(() {
      _counter+=200;
      progress = _counter/widget.max;
    });
    (await prefs).setInt(_storageKey, _counter);
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
        _storageKey = '${now.year}-${now.month}-${now.day}_${widget.text}_${widget.headline}';
        addElement();
        headline = widget.headline;
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies(){
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    
    prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs){
    _counter = prefs.getInt(_storageKey)?? 0;
    progress = _counter/widget.max;
    setState(() {});
  });}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap:_incrementCounter,
          child:Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 30, 0, 32),
            child: Row(children: [
            Icon(widget.icon, color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255), size: 50),
            Expanded(child: Text(
             '$_counter / ${widget.max.toInt()} ${widget.text}',
              style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 30)
            )),
            ],)
        ),
        LinearProgressIndicator(value: progress, 
        color: widget.color, 
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(49, 255, 255, 255),
        minHeight: 12,)
        ],
    )
      );
  
}
}
```

I would like to see that my function function() change to attributes of the TrackingElementState class

Comment: Extract state that must be shared into its own class, create an instance and pass that instance to your widgets; look into ValueNotifier and other similar classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you show me that in an code example?